# Select from numpy array by column with multiple logical conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I can select rows from a numpy array where the second element is 7 by using `myarray[myarray[:,1]==7]`. How can I extend this to select rows where the second element is 7 or 9? E.g. something like `myarray[myarray[:,1]==7|==9]` (obviously that doesn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `a[(a[:,1] == 7) | (a[:,1] == 9)]` for example:

```
In [6]: a = np.array([[4,7,8], [6,9,0], [4,4,4]])

In [7]: a[(a[:,1] == 7) | (a[:,1] == 9)]
Out[7]: 
array([[4, 7, 8],
       [6, 9, 0]])
```

Another option is to use `numpy.logical_or`

```
In [15]: a[np.logical_or(a[:, 1] == 7, a[:,1] == 9)]
Out[15]: 
array([[4, 7, 8],
       [6, 9, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) if you want to elegantly include more elements for selection, as shown in the code and sample run next up.

Code -

```
select_elements_list = [7,9] # Edit this to include more numbers if needed
row_mask = np.in1d(myarray[:,1],select_elements_list) # mask of valid rows
myarray_out = myarray[row_mask,:] # Output with selected rows based on mask
```

Thus, essentially would be a one-liner like so -

```
myarray_out = myarray[np.in1d(myarray[:,1],[7,9]),:]
```

Sample run -

```
In [15]: myarray
Out[15]: 
array([[8, 7, 7, 8, 8],
       [8, 9, 8, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 7, 8, 7],
       [7, 8, 8, 7, 8]])

In [16]: myarray[:,1]
Out[16]: array([7, 9, 9, 8])

In [17]: row_mask = np.in1d(myarray[:,1],[7, 9])

In [18]: row_mask
Out[18]: array([ True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [19]: myarray[row_mask,:]
Out[19]: 
array([[8, 7, 7, 8, 8],
       [8, 9, 8, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 7, 8, 7]])
```